# How to lock a website with password in google?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to lock youtube for reasons I'm not going to detail and I tried this script, but it only asks for the password. Nothing else happens, not even the console.log(). Any suggestions?

```js
  var pass = prompt("YouTube is locked. Password to unlock");
  if (pass != "password") {
    document.getElementById('watch7-content').innerHTML = location.replace("google.com");
    console.log('wrong');
  }
```

What I'm trying to do is ask for the password with prompt() and if it's not the password it'll redirect to google.com. It uses the video player as a reference for the url replacement, but i don't know if it works. Again, I don't think it's even working because it won't even console.log()...

Comment: Did you check the browser's console for errors? When does this script run? Does the page have an element `#watch7-content` at that point? Why are you referencing this element anyway? `location.replace()` doesn't return a value, so assigning it to the `innerHTML` seems odd.

Comment: Even if the element existed, it would reload the page before logging.

Comment: @Ivar i just followed [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.aspl),


but i just double checked and i'm a complete idiot ‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Comment: also, it runs whenever you reload the page/run a new yt instance

Comment: @TheNeto06 With " When does this script run?", I meant at what stage. Tampermonkey has a [`@run-at` header](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at) in which you can define when the script should run. If it runs at `document-start`, the `watch7-content` class wont yet be available. But if you're not going to use it and just redirect the user, then it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`location.replace` does perform a reload the page and this is the case why your console.log is not visible in console. If you move console.log on top of `location.replace` and you preserve console history (so it is not cleared between reloads) you will see it is executed successfully.

Also make sure to use full url with `location.replace`:

```js
location.replace('https://google.com')
```